# Unable to use 'Helper' booleans in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, boolean

I'm trying to use 'helper booleans'. I'm showing some TSX, but I don't think it changes anything.

```
const hasCountry = state.insuredInfo.country?.Country;

...

{hasCountry && (
   <PresentationalTextfield
       label={'Primary Domicile Country'}
       defaultValue={state.insuredInfo.country.Country}
    />
)}
```

But despite the helper being truthy, `defaultValue` still complains that the value *might* be undefined.

> Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
> index.tsx(26, 3): The expected type comes from property 'defaultValue' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { label: string; defaultValue: string; }'

Ditching the helper method, and declaring it inline works just fine.

```
{state.insuredInfo.country?.Country && (
   <PresentationalTextfield
       label={'Primary Domicile Country'}
       defaultValue={state.insuredInfo.country.Country}
    />
)}
```

Comment: `hasCountry` isn't a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates), just a boolean - it doesn't narrow the type of `state.insuredInfo.country.Country`.

Comment: Could you post a [mcve] that can be dropped into a standalone IDE like [the TypeScript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mbdAPw)? There is a new feature in TS4.4 [which tracks aliased conditions](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-4-beta/#cfa-aliased-conditions) that might do what you want, but without a reproducible example I can't be sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be thinking of [this new feature](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-4-beta/#cfa-aliased-conditions) in the TypeScript 4.4 **beta**. With that new feature, your code does look like TypeScript would recognize the aliased type guard and therefore succeed.

For your problem right now, you can simply add an exclamation mark after your expression to tell TypeScript "I'm sure this isn't undefined/null", e.g. like this:

```js
{hasCountry && (
   <PresentationalTextfield
       label="Primary Domicile Country"
       defaultValue={state.insuredInfo.country.Country!}
    />
)}
```